# Trying to loop through all entries in a datastore object and adding post numbers in dictionary

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql

I am parsing the contents of a page into JSON, and I am doing it by going through each post of the datastore object which is returned after the query. But my loop only goes through one iteration before returning the value.

The code for this is:

```python
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    #Getting all the entries of the page
    posts = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Blog ORDER BY time_created DESC")
    logging.info("Number of posts=" + str(posts.count()) ) 
    #Looping through them all to get the JSON text
    for post in posts:
        json_data = {
            'post' : {
                'subject': post.subject,
                'content': post.blog,
                'day'    : post.day_created.strftime('%d %b %Y')
            }
        }
        json_text = json.dumps(json_data)

    self.write('{"allposts":'+json_text+'}')
```

As you can see the loop is supposed to go through all the posts, I included a logging line to check the number of posts in the object and it returns the number of posts present.

the input would be a datastore object as such : `<google.appengine.ext.db.GqlQuery object at 0x0427FD90>`

This contains 3 entities: `subject`, `blog` and `day_created`

The output of this function is supposed to be a JSON object with posts ordered as such :

```
{
 'allposts:' 
     {'post1': 
            {
             'subject' : ' ... ', 
             'content': ' ... ' , 
             'day' : ' .. ' 
            }
    ,
     .... 
    ,
     'postn' :
          {
           ....
          }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On every iteration you are overwriting the `json_text` with

```
json_text = json.dumps(json_data)
```

You might want to concatenate the results like this

```
json_text += json.dumps(json_data)
```

[As per the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43648/discussion-between-bhargav-and-thefourtheye), your requirement is little different. So, something like this will work for you

```
for index, post in enumerate(posts, 1):
    json_data["post{}".format(index)] = {
           'subject': post.subject,
           'content': post.blog,
           'day'    : post.day_created.strftime('%d %b %Y')
    }

print {"allposts": json_data}
```

Comment: That operator is not applicable to dictionary and string types, buy the general idea should work. I have to find a way to somehow concatenate the dictionary. Using the ```dict``` constructor and updating should probably help.

Comment: @Bhargav You mean to say that, `json_text` is a dict?

Comment: Yes, aren't JSON objects in python dictionaries ?

Comment: @Bhargav `json.dumps` will convert the python objects to JSON sting. What exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to iterate through posts and add them to a dictionary to be converted to a JSON object. I tried using the += operator but got the error ```unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'dict' and 'str'
```.

Comment: @Bhargav I am sorry, I have to say that the question is not very clear. Can you please show an example, with few input data and the expected output?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43648/discussion-between-bhargav-and-thefourtheye)